# Web service work fine in chrome, but not in firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, web-services

I am trying to call external web service, its work fine in chrome, but not in firefox and IE. In chrome, it returns `'true'`, but in firefox, it returns `'0 error'`, it here is my complete code...

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnCall").click(function (event) {
            var campaignid = 1000007;
            var r_source_id = 1000008;
            var parameters = "{'CompanyName': '" + document.getElementById('txtCompanyName').value + "', 'name': '" + document.getElementById('txtName').value + "', 'title': '', 'email':'" + document.getElementById('txtEmail').value + "', 'phone':'" + document.getElementById('txtPhoneNo').value + "', 'web_url':'', 'no_of_emp':'0', 'c_Currency_id':'100', 'r_source_id':'" + r_source_id.toString() + "', 'industry_ID':'1', 'city':'', 'country_ID':'" + document.getElementById('ddlCountry').value + "', 'cur_solution':'','pur_timeline':'','comments':'', 'year_sell_erp':'2013', 'support':'', 'bpgroup_ID':'1', 'C_Campaign_ID':'" + campaignid.toString() + "', 'R_STATUS_ID':'1000033', 'C_Region_ID':'100', 'CreatedBy':'1000012', 'salesrep_id':'1000012', 'ad_org_id':'1000001', 'ad_client_id':'1000001', 'UpdatedBy':'100', 'AccessKey':'caff4eb4fbd6273e37e8a325e19f0991'}";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://cloudservice.softwareonthecloud.com/service.asmx/SetLead",
                data: parameters,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function (msg) {
                    AjaxSucceeded(msg);
                },
                error: AjaxFailed
            });
        });
    });
    function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
        alert(result.d);
    }
    function AjaxFailed(result) {
        alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
    }  
</script>
```

Here is I have upload this function [URL for testing](http://register.viennaadvantage.com/test.aspx)

Comment: are you loading jQuery twice?

Comment: It appears as though you are trying to make a CORS request. jQuery does not support CORS requests in IE < 10, and in the old version of jQuery you are using, it probably doesn't work in firefox either.

Comment: Is there any solution/trick, that it will work in Firefox?

Comment: There is a solution that will fix it in firefox and IE. Make a proxy script on your server (the one serving the page that makes the request) that requests data from the webservice for you. Have your client script request from your server, and your server requests from the webservice, thus avoiding the cross-origin problem.

Comment: you know it is returning one 500 error even in chrome before the 200 success

Comment: @Scott;I don't know, but I have check the DB and record is inserting.

Comment: @Kevin, How can I make a proxy script on server? Can you give me any reference link?

Comment: I don't have a link that supports ASP and i'm not an ASP developer, so i won't be of much help there.

Comment: Have you written the webservice? If you have, using what? Your webservice can support CORS requests, then it will work with firefox.

Comment: no... how can I do this?

Comment: @nunespascal; how will I know the web service support CORS request?

Comment: The webservice server needs to add a custom http header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with a value of `*`

Comment: how can I do this? Should I add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *  on top of the web service method?

Comment: No, that goes into the web.config file. Added a more detailed answer, hope it explains a few things

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are getting this error cause you are trying to call a web service on another domain. This violates the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). This is a security limitation. Most older browsers will deny such requests.

You will need to setup  [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) if you want to access a different domain the webservice in javascript.

> Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that allows a web
>   page to make XMLHttpRequests to another domain. Such "cross-domain"
>   requests would otherwise be forbidden by web browsers, per the same
>   origin security policy. CORS defines a way in which the browser and
>   the server can interact to determine whether or not to allow the
>   cross-origin request

If you have access to the webservice code, you can enable CORS requests at the server.
[Enable cors](http://enable-cors.org/) is a good resource. Here is some [explaination on cors](http://encosia.com/using-cors-to-access-asp-net-services-across-domains/)

On IIS 7, you need to set a few custom headers in your web.config.

```
<system.webserver>
 <httpprotocol>
  <customheaders>
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
  </customheaders>
 </httpprotocol>
</system.webserver>
```

[Here are the steps for IIS6](http://enable-cors.org/server_iis6.html)

**Security Note**: For an example here, I have allowed all requests to the server. You may want to limit this to selected domains if you are serving sensitive data.

WCF based requests too can be inspected via the `WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest` and appropriate headers can be sent out.

CORS requests are not supported on older browsers. You can see the full [browser compatibility list here](http://enable-cors.org/client.html)

If you must support older browsers, or cannot change the webservice, you can always host a webservice proxy on your server. You send the request to your server, and your server requests the data from the original webserivce. This works fine, cause it does not violate the cross origin policy. A simple http handler can server as the proxy on your server.

Here is what a sample http handler proxy to a REST webservice would look like:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
  WebClient myClient = new WebClient(); 

  //Fetch response on your server
  string response = myClient.DownloadString("http://example.com/webservice/webMethod");

  // Send response to your javascript.
  context.Response.Write(response);
}
```

You could then call this handler as required from javascript.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. the code mentioned in your answer, <system.webserver> already in web.config

Comment: I also, add the web service in my question and whatever required all things are in my question. Can you please try on your end?

Comment: Just checked. I don't receive the CORS Header. The setting I mentioned is for IIS 7. Your server should be sending a custom http header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. I do not see this header in the response.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using JSONP or easyXDM framework.

For JSONP you should only change one $.ajax attribute. Set `dataType:"jsonp"`. In that case server should return json and function name, in this format: `funcName(<JSON structure>)`. This is available for "GET" request only, but you are using "POST" here. You could try switch to "GET" request call.

If that is not possible you should consider using javascript [easyXDM framework](http://easyxdm.net/wp/) or CORS settings explained before, easyXDM has own cors component which enables it on older browsers.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I don't have control on server web service. But its only returning "true" or "false" as string.

Comment: Yes, JSONP is for GET requests only, I din't saw that. Thanks flup.

Answer (score 1):

Your request violates the Same Origin Policy.

Write a proxy service for the service in your own application.
Post the data it receives to the remote service and relay the answer.

This'll have the extra advantage that you can keep the AccessKey private.
You can add it to the request on your server before posting it to the remote server.

If this is way too much effort, ask the developers of the original service to also add a web page that calls it, on their server. Then you can add this web page in an IFrame.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having issues with CORS in Edge... my web service worked in Chrome, Firefox, and older IE.  Ultimately I had to update Edge and it worked.  Here is the list of supported browsers / versions for CORS:

[Enable CORS Browser Support](https://enable-cors.org/client.html)